# How to handle quoting of HTML in JavaScript document.write

Tags: javascript, html

I'm using `document.write` to take an array of images and I want to add an `onclick` event handler to each image by looping through this array. I'm having a very hard time figuring out where to put quotes in this JavaScript code:

```js
for (index = 0; index < buildings.length; index++) {
    document.write(
        "<img onclick='" + setPhoto() +   
        "' id='" + images[index].id + 
        "' src='" + images[index].src + 
        "' width='50' height='50'/>"
    );
};
```

All help is appreciated.

Comment: And what's your question?

Comment: It looks like you are looping through `buildings`, but then trying to output from `images`, could this be your problem? Hard to tell because you don't give enough details on what issue you are encountering

Comment: the quoutes in the given snippet of code look fine - depending on the output of the setPhoto function - if setPhoto is the command to run on click, then you are wrong, if setPhoto returns a string with the command to run on click, then you should be OK depending on that it returns ... also, your buildings array should be the same length (or shorter) than your images array, otherwise you'll have issues - but as your question is only about where to put quotes, then it seems ok apart from the aforementioned potential issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty much no one uses [document.write](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/write) anymore. Read the disclaimer in the docs

> Note: as document.write writes to the document stream, calling document.write on a closed (loaded) document automatically calls document.open which will clear the document.

---

You're better off doing something like this

```
for (var index = 0, img; index < buildings.length; index++) {
  img = document.createElement('img');
  img.src = images[index].src;
  img.width = 50;
  img.height = 50;
  img.onclick = setPhoto;
  document.body.appendChild(img);
}
```

This will attach the images to `document.body` but you could attach them to any other element you wanted